# Embedding UIViewcontrollers inside UICollectionviewCells

Tags: ios, design-patterns, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview

In my app I have a home page which has a Card/Grid Layout with multiple section. So `UICollectionView` is the obvious choice here. But these cards vary a lot in design, loading data and their functionality too. So putting all those in one single controller would be cumbersome, complex and hard to maintain. So we thought we need to separate these out into their own `UIViewControllers`. Each handles a type of card and calculates its contentSize to be shown inside a card. Our main home page controller is only responsible for putting those `viewcontroller` views inside the `UICollectionView` cells.

To summerize,

- A HomeViewController which has a [CollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/index.html)
- Every  view inside the collectionViewCell and its data are maintained by its own controller Class.
- All the instances of the controller are inside the HomeViewController and [added as its children](http://www.objc.io/issue-1/containment-view-controller.html).- [Apple Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html)
- [The appearance call](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW14)s to all the children viewControllers are made by ourselves since, the contentSize (Which is used as the item size for the collectionView layout) calculation of the controller views need the view to be loaded and data to be set.

My question is this, is this design choice right? Or what approach would you chose to implement such a screen? Since we create a lot of viewControllers (one for every cell), does this affect memory or performance? And If I want to cache only some viewControllers or load them as the user scrolls or when its time to add it to the collectionView cell, how do I go about it as calculating the size of that cell depends upon the data and the views while laying out the CollectionView layout.

Answer (score 1):

I think your approach is valid and from a theoretical standpoint it makes sense to separate a view from its data. But, in this case I would prefer to have the UICollectionViewCell subclass implement its own data, basically acting as a viewController. This will simplify your code a bit since you don't need the added viewControllers and the code that comes with them; instead you can simply add your tableView to the cell's contentView. This seems more natural to me, as then you can have HomeViewController's collectionView automatically handle calling its delegates when cells are moved offscreen and on, and during the loading process. You won't need to send messages to cells about who they are or when they should load, this will all be taken care of for you automatically. Also, I really don't think having the view lifecycle methods on each cell is valuable, and is less intuitive than having a cell load and refresh as part of a collectionView. Either way works, good luck!

Comment: I completely understand when you say it seems like an overkill. May be I was not too clear when I said design t, loading data vary a lot from card to card. A card might even have a tableView inside, or a another collectionView, or some complex set of views. Like those tableView delegates or those other Views inside those views. So I will need a "an Object that handles a view and its data", which sounded like a definition of a UIViewController to me. So I decided to use a viewcontroller.

Comment: And about using a viewcontroller for a section, there could be similar type of cards again pop up in different section, so what type of cards could be there in each section is not defined untill I fetch the data from the server. These informations (type of card, the data or how it should look) is defined in the server side. So i will end up creating a controller that should know how to handle every type of card.

Comment: I am facing the same problem now, what I did is take a screenshot of the View Controller's view save it in cache and use that screenshot in  UICollectioVIewCell everything is fine except a choppy scroll during the first time, Since it creates the view and takes screenshot when the cell loads for the first time. Need some suggestions or improvements

Comment: hey guys...i need same...have you found any solution?